# How do I set a loading state when i'm fetching data outside a page function in next 13?

Tags: next.js

From the docs, this is how you fetch data, but since it's outside the function, how do I track the loading state so users can know when a data section is loading.

```
async function getData() {
  const res = await fetch('https://api.example.com/...');
  if (!res.ok) {   
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data');
  }
  return res.json();
}

export default async function Page() {
  const data = await getData();

  return <main></main>;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom hooks for that:

useData.js

```
async function useData() {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  cost [error, setError] = useState(false)
const [data, setData] = useState()

useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  setLoading(true)
  const res = await fetch('https://api.example.com/...');
  if (!res.ok) {
    setError(true)
    return
  }
  setError(false)
  setLoading(false)
  setData(res.json())
}
fetchData()
}, [])

return {loading, error, data}
}
```

//page

```
export default function Page() {
  const {data, loading, error} = useData();

if(loading){ return <p>Loading...</p>}
if(error){ return <p>Error...</p>}
if(!data){ return <p>No data!!!</p>}

  return <main></main>;
}
```

Later, you can set up your hook to use an uri param so you can reuse this hook in multiple pages.